# How do I browse the internet from a Linux system masquerading it as a Windows or OSX system?

Tags: browser

Hi I'd like to browse the internet from Chromium or Firefox on a Kubuntu system, but disguise my OS as Win/OS. Googling didn't help, but I'm not really sure I'm searching for the correct thing, since I'm not entirely sure what terminology to use for doing something like this..

I'll also add that there's no nefarious intentions, Time Warner's customer service chat app window says it runs only on Win/OSX, and as being a customer I'd like to enlist their online assistance from my Linux system.

Comment: Search for ways to tweak your browser's User-Agent String. That's the main thing that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incidentally, the terminology you're looking for is called ["user agent" or "useragent"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) and it's controlled through your web browser. Most of the web browsers have plugins available where you can override this string and send any value you want, or choose from a list of known ones for the different browser/OS options available.

These plugins make it so that your browser can change its useragent so that it "fools" websites into thinking your using browserX when using browserY. This has worked for me in the past on certain sites. Here's one such plugin for Firefox, called [user-agent-switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/), for example.

#### Background

When a browser connects to a website, it sends a strings such as this identifying itself using this string, "user agent".

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36

The details of the above are as follows:

[image: ss of user agent info]

The above is Chrome's string, from a Linux system. You can see what yours is by navigating to this website, [User Agent String.Com](http://www.useragentstring.com/).

By using a plugin such as the one mentioned above, you can manipulate your browser's "user agent" to be anything you want. In this case you're changing it to match a "user agent" string for another browser, in this case say Internet Explorer (IE).

Something like this:

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you use the Firefox add-on, go and download this file: http://techpatterns.com/downloads/firefox/useragentswitcher.xml

You can import the contents of the file (a nice, long list of possible user agents you can use) using the User Agent Switcher option to "Edit User Agents":

Tools > Default User Agent > Edit User Agents > Import

You will be prompted to browse to the location of the XML file you just downloaded. You will need to select it and click OK.

If successful, you will notice a list of user agents (longer and more comprehensive than what comes with the add-on by default) that you can choose from by going to the aforementioned menu:

Tools > Default User Agent